# OpenVPN - TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Tags: vpn

I have tried to set up a OpenVPN on my pi, using this guide: http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/#awesm=~oBvYD8BOiTdCQN

I cannot connect with the following error being generated:

> UDP link local: (not bound)
>   UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xx.xxx.x.xx:1194
>   TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
>   TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
>   SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting

Looking here (https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/253-tls-error-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds-check-your-network-connectivity.html) this is a common error which suggests problems with:

1. Firewall
2. Port forwarding
3. Wrong server address
4. Windows whitelist problems

Regarding 1:
I run the following script prior to connecting, which is meant to punch a hole in the firewall (see step 12 of the guide) - this is meant to be automated but I can't find where to place it to make this happen, but that is a question for another post. For now i run this manually:

> #!/bin/sh
>   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.1$

I execute with "&& echo OK || echo Failed" and it executes fine.

So, although I am not very well versed in this stuff, I believe the firewall issue is not the issue.

Regarding 2:
IP address for my PI is static at 192.168.0.20; port forwarding is set to 1194 (see config files below)

Regarding 3:
I have stared at this for quite a while now, but can't see the problem. Here is my server.config file:

> local 192.168.0.20
>   dev tun proto udp
>   port 1194
>   ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
>   cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/pi_server.crt
>   key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/pi_server.key
>   dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
>   server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>       # server and remote endpoints
>   ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
>       # Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server
>   push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
>       # Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet
>   push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
>       # your local subnet
>   push "route 192.168.0.20 255.255.255.0"
>       # Set primary domain name server address to the SOHO Router
>       # If your router does not do DNS, you can use Google DNS 8.8.8.8
>   push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
>       # Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
>       # 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
>       # overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
>   push "redirect-gateway def1"
>   client-to-client duplicate-cn
>   keepalive 10 120
>   tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
>   cipher AES-128-CBC
>   comp-lzo
>   user nobody
>   group nogroup
>   persist-key persist-tun
>   status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
>   log /var/log/openvpn.log
>   verb 1

Regarding 4.
I am trying to connect from Ubuntu.

Responding to Goldilock's comment below:

Output of `iptables -L POSTROUTING`, *after* running the firewall script, gives:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Running `iptables -L` gives:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination

I am not sure what I am looking for here.

At this point I remain pretty stumped. I feel like I have looked at numerous server.config files and multiple guides, but I can't see what the problem might be.

If anyone can spot any problems that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should include the output of `iptables -L POSTROUTING` from *after* you run that command.  If you are running a firewall, it may not help since `-A` is append to the end of the rules, and ones before it take priority.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your problem could be the keys and not the firewall, some of the commons issues when connecting a Raspberry Pi and a VPN server is the OpenVPN version, for instance, if your server is using (2.4) and the client is using 2.3 (as I might guess due to the date of the tutorial) the keys won't be compatible, make sure both are using the latest version.

you can start by executing this:

```
sudo openvpn --version
```

if both versions are different, 2.3 vs 2.4, you will need to upgrade one or downgrade one.

now, **for the server configuration**, I had issues with UDP, so, maybe you can try with TCP

```
port 1194
proto tcp                          # we use TCP
dev tun                            # TUN kernel module enabled
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key 
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"    # optional
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"    # optional
keepalive 10 120
tls-crypt myvpn.tlsauth           # I use tls-crypt over tls-auth
cipher AES-256-CBC
compress lz4-v2                   # opptional compression
push "compress lz4-v2"            # opptional compression
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log        # server logs location
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"  # optional
```

in the above example, I'm pushing DNS from the server to the client to have access to internet besides the VPN, you can remove

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

if you don't want it

the above should go on your server.conf file on `$OPENVPN_HOME/server.conf` (if you didn't change the default location it should be `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`)

**on the client side**

```
client
tls-client
ca /home/donhk/open/ca.crt        # server certificate
cert /home/donhk/open/pibox.crt   # client certificate
key /home/donhk/open/pibox.key    # client key
tls-crypt /home/donhk/open/myvpn.tlsauth # server auth file
proto tcp                         # we use TCP
remote X.X.X.X 1194 tcp           # server de
dev tun                           # your server must have tun or tap module enabled at kernel level
topology subnet
cipher AES-256-CBC                # this should be the same as server
log /var/log/openvpn.log          # client logs location
pull
script-security 2                # optional
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf  # optional
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf # optional
```

notice that I'm using

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

it is to enable the pushed DNS from the server, those are optional if you don't want

you can write the client.conf or a client.ovpn and use it as

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

or manage it as part of the service,  and start the client as

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@client.service
```

before start up the client make sure that both, the server and the client are using the correct time settings (ntp module)

```
sudo timedatectl
```

if you get this

```
 Local time: Sun 2018-04-01 19:29:27 UTC
 Universal time: Sun 2018-04-01 19:29:27 UTC
 RTC time: n/a
 Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
 NTP enabled: no       # ntp is not enabled
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
 DST active: n/a
```

it means that the certificates won't be able to be validated (because there is no date on the server/client and the certificates expiration date may be invalid)

to install the ntp and configure it you can use

```
sudo yum install -y ntp
sudo systemctl start ntpd
```

set your time zone

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone  Your_TimeZone
```

once the above is set, and if your firewall is properly configured, the client should be able to talk to the server

I wrote how I accomplished it here:

[Set up a media server on a Raspberry Pi and access it from anywhere](https://donhk.wordpress.com/2018/04/04/custom-plex-setup/)

Excerpt:

**[Warning]** This will be a long post

Hope that helps